# There is a smart way to solve this 2x2 system of linear equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

I was helping a high school student to study system of equations and he showed me this problem:

\begin{align}\frac{x-a}{b} + \frac{y-b}{a} &= x-a \\
\frac{x+y-b}{a}+\frac{y+b}{b} &= 3 .
\end{align}

I suggested to him to solve for one of the variables (e.g.. $x$) and then substitute, but the problem becomes painfully hard, because of all the literals, and fractions. So, there is a intelligent way to solve this system of equations?

Comment: use that we get from the first equation $$\left\{\left\{y\to \frac{a^2 (-b)+a^2+a b x-a x+b^2}{b}\right\}\right\}$$

Comment: A way to approach this is to solve for expressions instead of individual variables, for instance $x-a$ or $x-a\over b$...

Answer (score 4):

Rearrange the question into this:
$$(x-a)\left(\frac1b-1\right)+(y-b)\frac1a=0\\
(x-a)\frac1a+(y-b)\left(\frac1a+\frac1b\right)=0$$
Then, provided the determinant of the $2\times2$ matrix is non-zero, there is exactly one solution.

Comment: This is quite a good idea, and makes plain why we get the solution $x = a, y = b$.

Answer (score 0):

Given the system

> $\frac{x-a}{b} + \frac{y-b}{a}=x-a\\
> \frac{x+y-b}{a}+\frac{y+b}{b}=3$

it is worth rearranging prior to solving, as

$$ax-a^2-axb+yb-b^2+a^2b=0\\
bx+by-b^2+ya+ab-3ab=0$$

Separating the variables and constants,

$$a(1-b)x+yb=a^2+b^2-a^2b\tag 1$$
$$bx+(a+b)y=b^2+2ab\tag 2$$

The "slopes" of the two equations are generally unrelated, and except for multiplying by similar quantities across both equations, we can't isolate variables:

$$(1)\cdot (a+b)+(2)\cdot (-b)\\ \to a(a+b)(1-b)x+b(a+b)y-b^2x-b(a+b)y=(a+b)(a^2+b^2-a^2b)-b^3-2ab^2\\
(a(a+b)(1-b)-b^2)x=a^3+a^2b-ab^2-a^3b-a^2b^2\\
(a^2+ab-a^2b-ab^2-b^2)x=a(a^2+ab-a^2b-ab^2-b^2)\\
x=a\tag 3$$

With this solution in hand, we immediately see that $y=b$.

Comment: And yes, this isn't much better on the "painfully hard" scale than other methods presented.  In fact, it's much worse than my initial suggestion of using $x-a$ as a quantity to solve for...